# Spring Security - POST method for antMatcher (not antMatchers)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-config

I have two configuration:

@Order(1)

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/api/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new ApiAuthenticationEntryPoint(objectMapper));
}
```

@Order(2)

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/product/**").hasRole(SecurityRoles.USER)
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
    .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
    .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
```

I need to add functionality to register a new user with the REST endpoint **`/api/users`** with no authentication. The other **`/api/**`** endpoints should remain with basic authentication. How to do this? I can't see the method `antMatcher` with an option to choose the http method type.

Edit:

I need something like this:

```
http.antMatcher("/api/users", HttpMethod.POST.toString).permitAll()
    .and()
    .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
(...)
```

Comment: There isn't one for `antMatcher` (singular). The interface is intentionally minimal. [The JavaDoc says](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#antMatcher-java.lang.String-) "If more advanced configuration is necessary, consider using `requestMatchers()` or `requestMatcher(RequestMatcher)`."

Comment: See my edit. Could you show me how to do this, please? Because of two configurations (REST + WWW) I have a problem how to properly configure my API endpoints with use of antMatchers (plural). I could only configure all API endpoints `/api/**`. But don't know how to permit one specific `/api/users/` with POST.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that with `antMatchers()` though:

```
http
    .antMatcher("/api/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
```

The difference between `antMatcher(..)` and `antMatchers(..)` is that you use `antMatcher(..)` when you have separate security configuration classes. This could be necessary when you need to differentiate between:

- Authentication mechanisms (form login, basic authentication, ...)
- CSRF handling
- Session management
- Filters
- User details services
- ...

The `antMatchers(..)` on the other hand (within `authorizeRequests(..)`) is used to differentiate between authorization levels (which roles have access to certain endpoint).

In your case, the configuration falls under the latter, as you only need to differentiate between the authority of the `POST /api/user` endpoint.

---

However, if you really need mor granular control over which security configuration class that should be applied, then you should use [`RequestMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.11.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatcher.html) as mentioned in the comments.

This interface has a single `HttpServletRequest` argument and expects you to return a `boolean`. Since `HttpServletRequest` contains all information you need, such as the path and the HTTP method, you could properly tune which configuration class should apply. However, in this case it isn't necessary.